# Git: Switching branches

Tags: git

I created a new branch (backup-master) and pushed to it.
How can I switch my local branch back to master?

Comment: Hi, a question. What do you see if you do `git status`, `git branch -a` and `git log --oneline`? You can provide your answers in your question so it's easier for people to understand where you are relative to `git`

Comment: thanks astrochun, I have added the answers to the question.

Comment: How did you reset and create the `backup-master` branch? From your edited output, it looks like you kept working on `backup-master`. Do you still need the original `master` branch or can it be deleted (irrevocably)?

Comment: It’s a bit unclear what you want to do, if you can try to clarify/add more detail.

Comment: *"all my commits are not going to backup-master and not master."* Is there a "not" too many here? I am guessing your local commits are on `backup-master` and that you are confused and would want all of them to be merged to `master` and then push those upstream; is that correct?

Comment: This is not the actual output.  Those outputs do not match each other.

Comment: Hi @knittl I would like to go back on working master and not the backup-master, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi @tripleee thanks, I meant "now" going to backup-master and not master. My apologies.

Comment: Hi @tripleee yes I would like to merge and make all commits go to master only

Comment: This shows that have never pushed backup master. Please do `git branch -vv`

Comment: Whether or not that makes sense also depends somewhat on how you ended up in this situation and where you want to end up. If upstream has both `master` and `backup master` and your local changes have diverged from upstream, the situation is quite different and more complex than if you just have a local branch which you would like to graft back onto `master` and push upstream.

Comment: I suspect you just want to go back to `master` and merge in whatever you did on `backup-master`, in which case this could do the trick: `git checkout master` followed by `git checkout backup-master`. But I'm making quite a few assumptions and reading between the lines here...

Comment: hi @joanis, this is exactly it! thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that helped. I'll take a moment to fix the suggestion since I typed too fast: `git checkout master` followed by `git merge backup-master`, though I assume you had already figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is go back to the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```

and then merge in any commits you made on `backup-master` so you don't lose that work:

```
git merge backup-master
```